# mysql how to get 2nd highest value with group by and in a left join

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

```
(select id from owner where date_format(auction_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') = date_format(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')) as a
    left join (select owner_id,max(nb) as maxbid from auction group by owner_id) as b on a.id=b.owner_id
    left join (select owner_id,max(mb) as maxautobid from auction group by owner_id) as c on a.id=c.owner_id
```

For the second left join statement, i'm able to get the highest mb value. Can someone help me add a third left join statement so that i can get the second highest mb value??

Comment: When you ask sql query question please consider to provide sample data and desired output based on it. It may help you to get your answer faster and more accurate.

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't need a third join at all.  You can do your calculation in one join:

```
from (select id
      from owner
      where date_format(auction_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') = date_format(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')
     ) as a left join
     (select owner_id, max(nb) as maxbid, max(mb) as maxautobi
      from auction
      group by owner_id
     ) b
     on a.id=b.owner_id;
```

Getting the second largest value for `mb` then uses a trick, involving `substring_index()` and `group_concat()`:

```
   from (select id
          from owner
          where date_format(auction_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') = date_format(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')
         ) as a left join
         (select owner_id, max(nb) as maxbid, max(mb) as maxautobi,
                 substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(mb order by mb desc), ',', 2), ',', -1
                                ) as second_mb
          from auction
          group by owner_id
         ) b
         on a.id=b.owner_id;
```

The idea is to concatenate the values together, ordering by `mb`.  Then take the second element of the list.  The one downside is that the value is converted to a character string, even when it starts as a number.