# Limit a LEFT JOIN Subquery to 1 result

Tags: mysql, sql

The query below seems to LIMIT *all* the results when it's being LEFT JOINed, so the total in the subquery is just 1. How can I make it LIMIT so that I get a `1:1` match between `projects` rows and the last date stored in `projects_hours_archive` which stores records of `projects.projected_hours` that are collected on a cron job once per week?

`projected_hours_archive` has columns: `id`, `project_id`, `hours` and `datetime`.

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT( projected_hours_last.date, '|', projected_hours_last.number ) AS 'projected_last_info'
FROM
projects


LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM
    projected_hours_archive
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS projected_hours_last ON ( projected_hours_last.project_id = projects.id )

WHERE projected_hours > 0

GROUP BY projects.id
```

I tried to adopt using [MySQL Limit LEFT JOIN Subquery after joining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016719/mysql-limit-left-join-subquery-after-joining) but wasn't successful. If I remove the `LIMIT` in the subquery I get too many results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `group by` in the sub query and get maximum date per project.

EDIT: as per the OP comment, adding second max date.

The trick from this [mysql how to get 2nd highest value with group by and in a left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765752/mysql-how-to-get-2nd-highest-value-with-group-by-and-in-a-left-join) is used.

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT( projected_hours_last.secondMaxDate, '|', projected_hours_last.number ) AS 'projected_last_info'
FROM
projects


LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT project_id, max(date) as maxDate,
           substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(date order by date desc), ',', 2), ',', -1
                            ) as secondMaxDate
    FROM
    projected_hours_archive
    group by project_id
) AS projected_hours_last ON ( projected_hours_last.project_id = projects.id )

WHERE projected_hours > 0

GROUP BY projects.id
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put this in - I'm trying to get the second from last date.

Comment: @meder, there is a trick from this post to get second one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765752/mysql-how-to-get-2nd-highest-value-with-group-by-and-in-a-left-join. updated the answer, as data is not there, couldn't try.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question.

I suppose your field `projects.project_id` is unique (so there are **no duplicates in that table**). Otherwise, you can use `DISTINCT(projects.project_id)` or `GROUP BY projects.project_id` as you've used before.

**Solution #1 (using GROUP BY while joining):**

```
        SELECT  a1.project_id,
                GROUP_CONCAT(a2.date, '|', a2.number ) AS 'projected_last_info'
        FROM projects a1
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT b1.project_id, b1.date, b1.number
            FROM projected_hours_archive b1 
            ORDER BY b1.date DESC
            GROUP BY b1.project_id
        ) a2 ON a2.project_id = a1.project_id
        WHERE a1.projected_hours > 0
```

**Solution #2 (using LIMIT directly in subquery in SELECT statement):**

```
        SELECT  a1.project_id,
                (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a2.date, '|', a2.number )
                    FROM projected_hours_archive b1
                    WHERE b1.project_id = a1.project_id
                    ORDER BY b1.date DESC
                ) AS 'projected_last_info'
        FROM projects a1
        WHERE a1.projected_hours > 0
```